# Unable to fetch and update DB columns in Laravel (using Resource Controller & Collective Forms)

Tags: php, laravel, sql-update

Here's a little context to what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to make a Profile System where the user registers and is redirected to a Display Page, where all the User info like his name, email etc. are meant to be displayed. Since the registration form only has 2 fields (name / email) - the user has to update his other info like his gender/facebook ID/twitter ID etc etc. So I've an Edit button which takes the user to a form. Now on that form, I want his already-existing Name/Email to show up, while the other fields like Gender/FB/Twitter/Description are empty - once he fills those fields and presses Update, I want him to go back to Display Page and then be shown all this updated/new information i.e Gender/Name/Email/Twitter/Description. Following is my code so far:

**ProfileController.php** (Resource Controller):

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\CustomUser;


class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $customusers = CustomUser::get()->first();
        return view ('display',compact('customusers'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(CustomUser $customuser) 
    {
        return view ('edit',compact('customuser'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, CustomUser $customuser)
    {
        $customuser->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('display.index')->with('creation','Profile has been updated successfully!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**CustomUser.php** (Model):

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class CustomUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'customusers';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','username','email','gender','password','message','twitter','facebook',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**Display.blade.php** (Main Page):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div style="margin-top: 5.2%;" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            @if (Session::has('creation'))
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                {{ Session::get('creation') }}
            </div> 
            @endif
             {{ link_to_route('display.edit','Edit',[$customusers->id],['class'=>'btn btn-success']) }}

             {{$customusers->name}}
             {{$customusers->email}}
             {{$customusers->message}}
             {{$customusers->facebook}}
             {{$customusers->twitter}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

And finally, this is my **Edit.blade.php**:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<body style="height: 105.6vh;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" style="color: #fff; background-color: #113;font-family: 'Nunito',sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 2px;
                font-weight: bold;">
                    Edit Profile
            </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                        {!! Form::model($customuser,array('route'=>['display.update',$customuser->id],'method'=>'PUT')) !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Username']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::email('email',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Email']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-row">
                            <div class="col-5">
                                    {!! Form::select('gender', ['Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female'], null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Choose Gender']); !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                    {!! Form::text('facebook',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Facebook ID']) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                    {!! Form::text('twitter',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Twitter Handle']) !!}
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::textarea('message',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Talk about yourself']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::button('Edit',['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-danger col-lg-12']) !!}
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
@endsection
```

Now, when I click Edit and go to Edit.blade.php - all the fields are blank, when two of them (Name / Email) should have pre-filled blanks of what the user's credentials are, but that isn't the case - they are blank. And when I fill all the fields and press Update, it gives me "**The PUT method is not supported for this route**. What am I doing wrong here? I've been squabbling through the Internet for over 2 hours and I'm unable to find what I'm doing wrong here. Let me know there are any further info required for you to crack this problem of mine..

Comment: How do you declare your route in the route file?

Comment: `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::resource('/display','ProfileController');`

Comment: use `php artisan route:list` to make sure you are using the correct route and variable names.